# Javascript links that Google and other bots cant click?

Tags: javascript

I have a project where my employer want me to build an ad network.

The problem they have is with Google bots and other bots clicking on the links and thus draining the balance of advertisers.

I have seen somewhere that it's possible to use javascript links, instead of a standard `<a href=""></a>`. And that bots don't click such links.

My question is, can anyone give me an example of such link?

Or any resources I could find more details on that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Google bots respect no-index/no-follow

Comment: but other, so called 'bad bots' don't... I'm basically looking for a way to hide the url of a link, so that the bots won't be able to recognize.

Comment: I read it can be done with jQuery OnClick ="external url source".

Comment: Also, javascript links won't stop bots these days.

Comment: But if you want to try a Javascript link, it's `onClick="location.href='url'"` etc. This might stop some bots.

Comment: @Keith using like this:  `<a onClick="location.href='https://www.example.com/'" >example</a>`   ?

Comment: What about this logic: have a jQuery script with a `$variable = 'https://www.example.com'`, and then somehow appending it to the link: `<a onClick="location.href='$variable'" >example</a>`. I guess that would be a bit more bulletproof. I this possible?

Comment: Yes,  you could also try adding the onClick using addEventListener, that will obscure it a tad more too..